# How to create a facebook ad inside the sandbox via api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create a sandbox facebook ad.

I managed to create a Campaign and an AdSet but when I try to create an AdCreative or an Ad I get following exception:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1885183,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Article of the ad was created with an app in development mode",
        "error_user_msg": "The advertisement was created by an app in development mode. It must be public to create this ad.",
        "fbtrace_id": "123456789"
    }
}
```

Does this mean its impossible to create even sandbox-ads as long as the app is in dev mode (not reviewd)?
If yes whats the point of the sandbox?

I followed this tutorial using Postman and curl step by step and everything worked until 4. Create Ad Creative. : https://github.com/keboola/ex-facebook-graph-api/wiki/Sandbox-Ad-Account-Testing-Environment

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [this is a known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2213642625549771/) on Facebook and it's not possible to create AdCreative for app in dev mode.

What I did is: I made a screencast for the possible part and make it possible for the reviewer to get access to the website to test it himself, this is also confusing, since there is no user interface where to check the created ad in sandbox, I created new facebook account, add it as a tester to my app,  and send app for review explaining why ad can't be created, it was rejected the first time but I requested again and it got approved

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to post this question over the project issues
https://github.com/keboola/ex-facebook-graph-api/issues